# length or the number of checkboxes in one of the divs

Tags: jquery

for example I have the following:

```
<div class="both">
    <textarea data-id="1" name="t1">Value 1</textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" checked="checked" name="c1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1-2"  name="c1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1-3"  name="c1">
</div>
<div class="both">
    <textarea data-id="2" name="t2">Value 2</textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2-1"  name="c2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" checked="checked" name="c2">
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2-3" name="c2">
</div>
<div class="both">
    <textarea data-id="3" name="t3">Value 3</textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3-1"  name="c3">
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3-2" name="c3">
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3-3" checked="checked" name="c3">
</div>
```

I want to find out the number of checkboxes in first div element of both.

Stupid question, but I am new in this..

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count elements inside an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568757/how-to-count-elements-inside-an-object). Of course you have to get the selector right, which is perfectly covered in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.both:first input[type="checkbox"]').length
```

Comment: is wrong, you have not read the question properly but added a quick line of code to try and be the first post, if you are going to do that you could as least get it right

Comment: @des Because you were missing the `:first` selector, which made your answer wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I've skipped it (read question too fast to notice "first"), but well, I didn't even had 10 seconds to edit my post...

Comment: That's why downvotes can be removed after a question has been edited. As you can see, there is none left for your answer.

Comment: @Niko Yeah, got it. I'm still soooo new at stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div.both:first input:checkbox').length
```

More information: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.both:first input[type="checkbox"]').length
```

As the jQuery Doc says here http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

`input[type="checkbox"]` is better than `:checkbox`

> Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   [type="checkbox"] instead.